# In Dart-polymer I have been unable to find a way to keep a text-box scrolled to the bottom

Tags: textbox, scroll, dart, dart-polymer

I have found multiple ways to do this in various browsers and languages but nothing I can find has worked for Dart-polymer in Chrome.

Otherwise everything is very simple and standard:

```dart
<template> 
   <style>
      textarea {
        width:  825px;
      }
    </style>
    <div>       
      <textarea id="ta" rows="10" on-mouseover="{{on_mouse_over}}">                  
         {{message}}
      </textarea>       
    </div>
</template>
```

Thanks!

Comment: You could have added links to solutions in other languages. That had helped understanding what you actually want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is what you want:

```dart
@CustomTag('my-text')
class MyText extends PolymerElement {
  @observable String message = "";

  MyText.created() : super.created();

  void messageChanged(old) {
    var ta = $['ta'];
    ta.scrollTop = ta.scrollHeight;
  }

  void attached() {
    super.attached();
    new Timer.periodic(new Duration(seconds: 1), (_) => message += 'some text ${new DateTime.now()}\n');
  }
}
```

I added `id="ta"` to the `<textarea>` to make `$['ta']` work

Comment: Worked basically but did not scroll entirely to the bottom.  Clue: many of my messages to this textbox are immediately before and after calls for WebSocket work.  I used the Timer.periodic() with a delay of 2 seconds and it now seems to keep scrolled to the bottom of the textbox under normal circumstances at least.  So Thanks, you gave me not one but two vital clues in one post.  (PS I tried assigning scrollTop to scrollHeight AFTER each "message append" thinking this would solve the Asynchronous issue but it didn't work. )

Comment: I saw this effect too, but then I changed it that a newline was added at the end of the line (had it at the beginning previously), then the last text line was shown (only the empty last line was hidden). I thought this should be sufficient event when it's not perfect.